Gouging a constant-depth path in variable-height terrain
I have a large model (38M tris) of terrain (from LiDAR scans).

I will soon have a series of 1D paths, geolocated points representing detailed lat/lon gps coordinates along walking trails. These points will not have accurate elevation data.
For each trail, I want to conceptually:

Widen the infinitely-thin 1D path along the points to give them a set width (roughly "stroking" the path).
Lift the points of the path up to slightly above height of the terrain, and then
Lower the path straight down in Z to a certain offset depth, burning away the terrain

The end result would be as though a team of crack excavator operators dug down a specific depth all along each path, carving straight walls down. For example, if there's a winding path going up a mountain side, and the desired depth is 3 meters, then there should be a log flume with 3m walls etched into the terrain where the path is.
In case it matters, the end goal is to use the resulting mesh to carve a piece of wood to match the terrain, with slots along each path that I can use to highlight the path.
How would I possibly accomplish this with Blender? Is a boolean modifier a reasonable choice for the end step?

Edit
I was able to "stroke" the 1D curves to a fixed width using the Bevel option under Object Data Properties, selecting the Object mode, and choosing an object that was a two-point straight curve segment of the width I wanted. I then converted this curve into a mesh before performing the knife project from the accepted answer.
Using knife project works reasonably well, with two caveats:

Where curve segments overlap, or even self-intersect, faces end up not selected:



There appears to be some implicit tolerance in the knife projection that prevents it from creating clean edges that match the curve. Notice the polygons that are outside the curve, and the few cases where the curve exists but no polygons are selected:




How will be the "series of 1D paths" : do you have a huge spreadsheet file with lat/long to convert to Blender, or do you have curve objects in Blender with correct x,y coordinates ? Besides of that, I think I understand what you want to achieve but a sketch or simple visual example would quite useful.

@Lutzi I will originally have spreadsheet file to convert; I haven't picked an import format yet, but let's assume that I get each path converted into a Curve.

If if actually continuous paths that need to be carved, I'd do it like this:
You can take the paths and convert them to a mesh if they are curves, then add a skin modifier. Lower the radius so it's not very thick.
Apply the skin modifier and delete all the faces that are not pointing up. You can select one up facing face and then hit Shift+G->Normal to select all of them, Then Ctrl+i and delete the other faces. The pints where 2 paths meet might need some clean up.

This leaves you with a 2D set of paths that you can use in knife project. With the paths above the map, select the map and go into edit mode. Deselect everything and select the paths by pressing Ctrl+RMB on the other object. (Or LMB if that's what you use to select). Then, looking from above, go to the knife project tool:

This will project the 2D paths into the landscape with the cut selected. You can add them to a vertex group so they are easy to select later:

From here you can either move the selected faces down manually with proportional editing active, or you could give it a displacement modifier with the vertex group as the limiter.


Given that I'm starting with 38M triangles, I'm concerned by any steps where you say "manually". :) But otherwise, very helpful, thank you.

Thank you for this answer. Works pretty well. If you care, I've edited my question with a few screenshots showing caveats of this result.

If you have different points without the height converted into vertices, you can use a shrinkwrap modifier, in projection mode on the Z axis (with negative checked) to flatten them to the surface.

The 'offset' at the bottom of the modifier lets you burry them or place them above at the specified height.
If you want to dig holes at this location then yea, a boolean would work fine I think.
You can use a geometry nodes setup to turn the vertices into cylinders like this:

You need to create the cutter object separately. A cylinder with the origin at the bottom face would be fine, tho you can also give it a tamper and make the top face wider or give the bottom a round end if you need to.

The geometry node setup creates copies of that cylinder where the points are and makes them real, so you can use them in the boolean.
You will have to apply the shrink wrap modifier first or it will get confused when it tries to project over the holes
You'll also need to make the map solid before using a boolean on it. You can select the edges of the square and extrude them down, then scale them to 0 on the Z axis and fill the gap with 'F'

I think Phrogz needs a path with thickness, not just individual points. Else I misunderstood the question.

@Lutzi is correct; I'm sorry I don't have the data to show what I mean, but I need to take a 2D curve, give it width, loft the points to sit along the terrain above them, then carve down from those points a specific depth from the surface.

Ok, never mind the other answers. They work, so I won't delete or edit them, but I've found a much easier way:

Take your curve paths and convert them to a mesh. Then use Shrink wrap to project them onto the terrain like in the other answers and apply the transformation
Then you go to the terrain and add all the geometry to a vertex group.
Then add a Vertex Weight Proximity modifier with the paths as the Target object and affecting the vertex group you just created.
Then add a Displacement modifier with the the vertex group and set it to the Z axis.
The Midlevel on the Displacement modifier will control how deep the groove is. And the 'Highest' setting in the Vertex Weight Proximity modifier controls how far from the paths the mesh is affected. You can change the fallout type as well to make it sharp or smooth.
The controls are a bit wonky but I think it's a lot easier than the other method. It doesn't involve manual anything and can be adjusted as needed.
This method raises the terrain while not affecting the part next to the path. I don't really know how to make the area next to the paths go down instead, but if you don't want the geometry to move up, simply add another displacement modifier with the same settings and Midlevel but negative Strength and no vertex group. This will move the whole thing down the same amount.
The lower area might look like a series of cones instead of a smooth groove depending on how dense and big the path mesh is. If this is the case, add a subdivision mod to the path mesh to increase the amount of vertices.

I guess there might be a reason to choose Boolean over Displacement, if OP's intention is to inlay a strip with a  consistent rectilinear profile? The cut might conform to a strip more accurately than the non-planar faces.. but yes, both ways will have their own gotchas.,

@RobinBetts with this method the falloff mode can be adjusted to be a constant mode as well. If the terrain has 38M faces I don't think the unsharp edges will be that noticeable. Tbh with that geometry density I'd be surprised if the boolean actually works without exploding the pc

Yup, true, to all intents and purposes.
